# Fancy box is not working

Tags: jquery, magento

I want to load Fancy box  with iframe..

But it redirecting to me ..

this is the link
**`**http://192.232.214.244/suitnsave/index.php/suits.html**`**
on **firebug**

```
jQuery('a.quick').fancybox();
```

it is executing.. but still redirecting to new page

Any help

Comment: Include the HTML that has the container for fancybox

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: no error in console..

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox is having trouble detecting which type to use for the popup. If you specify one in your options, then Fancybox will work.

```
jQuery('a.quick').fancybox({type: 'iframe'});
```